# Javascript - verify the values of fields with dynamic names

Tags: javascript

I have a set of text fields qty with dynamic names: like `qty541` ; `qty542` ; `qty957`
formed by the word: `"qty"` and the `product id`

How can I verify if all my qty fields are empty or not with Javascript ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you use something like jQuery?

Comment: Yes, but I want also to use window.onbeforeunload, to prevent that the user quit the page and lose data when He have typed quantity in the qty fields...

Comment: It is easier with a unic Id for all the qty fields ? I can give a unic id "qty"...

Comment: ... or you could use a `class="qty"` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
<p>
 <input type="text" name="qty3232" value="43"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="qty5532" value="as"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="qty5521" value=""/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="qty3526" value="34"/>
</p>
<br/>
<h3>Log</h3>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

Javascript (no jQuery):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var log = document.getElementById('log');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type == 'text' && inputs[i].name.substring(0,3) == 'qty') {
        if (inputs[i].value == '') {
            log.innerHTML += inputs[i].name + " value empty.\n";
        } else {
            log.innerHTML += inputs[i].name + " value not empty.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jxmMW/

This is much easier using a selector in jQuery, though.

```
var log = $('#log');

$('input[name^="qty"]').each(function(){
    if (this.value == '') {
        log[0].innerHTML += this.name + " value empty.\n";
    } else {
        log[0].innerHTML += this.name + " value not empty.\n";
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jxmMW/1/

Comment: Thanks, what does log.innerHTML += inputs[i].name + " value empty.\n"; 

do ? :)

Comment: @Bizboss: It converts the DOM content of the `log` element to a string, then appends further content to that string, then tears down the DOM content of the `log` element and builds up new content with the updated string. I'd strongly recommend *not* using `+=` with `innerHTML`, but it does work.

Comment: @Bizboss - As you didn't include any markup/code to review, I use that to demonstrate the test. It simply appends the output on the right of the equal to within the PRE with id="log". Click on the link and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - I think for the purposes of a short demo, it works just fine. :)

Comment: Thanks:) I'm trying to make it with :
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
 return "Are you sure to close the page?";
 };
</script>

in a onsubmit event in my form...

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the elements of the form:

```
var form = document.getElementById('theForm');
var index;
var field;
for (index = 0; index < form.elements.length; ++index) {
    field = form.elements[index];
    if (field.name.substring(0, 3) === "qty") {
        // Check field.value here
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ihohe5)

The above assumes the form has an `id`, but however you get access to the `form` element, the rest follows.

---

**Off-topic**: A lot of this stuff is made much simpler by the utility functions available in various JavaScript libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They also smooth over browser differences (or outright browser bugs), allowing you to focus on the job in hand rather than worrying about browser inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a javascript framework like JQuery, Protoype, etc. With this framework you can create a search pattern in reg expr manner. If you unable to use one, it does need more work:

**One** way:

```
var formObj = document.forms[0]; //as an example
var fields = formObj.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i=0; i < fields.length, i++)
{
   if (fiedls[i].name.indexOf("qty") > 1)
   {
     //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 The first asnwer which is any good. But rather `fiedls[i].name.indexOf("qty") == 0` as this has to be the first 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS:

For example use class="quantity" on all fields and use [getElementsByClassName](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/05/getelementsbycl.html) - which almost takes us into jQuery mode

```
window.onbeforeunload=function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity"); // needs help in some browsers
  for (var i=0,n=elems.length;i<n;i++) {
    if (elems[i].value!="") {
      return "You have filled in a quantity");
    }
  }
}

window.onload=function() {
  document.forms[0].onsubmit=validate;
}

function validate() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity"); 
  for (var i=0,n=elems.length;i<n;i++) {
    if (elems[i].value=="") {
        alert("Please fill in a quantity");
        elems[i].focus();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

---

standard method:

```
function validate() {
  var elem;
  for (var i=0,n=this.elements.length;i<n;i++) {
    elem = this.elements[i];
    if (elem.name && elem.name.indexOf("qty")===0) {
      if (elem.value=="") {
        alert("Please fill in a quantity");
        elem.focus();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true; // allow submit
}
```

Comment: Be careful with recommendation of .getElementsByClassName(). This function is only available in new Javascrip of HTML5.

Comment: Hence the link to the needed extensions for un-supported browsers.