# How to reference HTML layer for javascript component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a component that can be used several times on the page. And I would like to keep the HTML and component configuration together.

```
<div id="myComponent">
   <table>
      <th>c1</th>
      ...
      <th>cX</th> 
   </table> 
</div>
<script>
  var componentApi = new MyModule.MyComponent($('#myComponent')[0]);
  // configure component through componentApi with ajax source and callback render funcions
</script>
```

But I'm not happy with this. First because I do not like referencing to id uniqueness (it makes templating complex), second, I do not like  unnecessary search for id through all document.

But my all alternative ideas does not work:

- I do not want to rely also on `script`'s id (to calculate previous
  sibling), because of the same reasons.
- And `.currentScript`  doesn't work in IE 11.
- `Div` doesn't have `onLoad` event...

Do we have better solution than searching for id through all document if only what we need is initialize component in the HTML with the HTML layer?

**Addition**:  I'm not sure that wish to keep component's HTML and component's JS configuration together harms DRY principle. They both compose "the configuration". And second, configuring the hierarchichy is not easy with flat `data-` attributes, that why the part of configuration is HTML. Finally the easiest way to configure HTML is to write a HTML.

**Addition**:  Other my though is that "popular configuration" (fully or partially reused) can be encapsulated into another "outer" component. Only fixed `id` value prevents encapsulation there. Of course I understand that `id` can be generated in the moment of creating HTML/DOM, but **I will be happy to find that there is  possibility to completely escape the referencing using id**.

**Addition**: In one phrase the problem there is that id is global (global scope, global search). And the "shadow dom"+"web component" will solve this easy in future, but may be anybody have an idea how Polymer authors polyfill this?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048432/create-reusable-document-fragment-from-the-dom

Comment: Why not put a `class` on all elements you want to initialize as a component, and run the script on all of them using the `.` selector?

Comment: Another option would be just to create the container html node in your component and add it to document object.

Comment: @JNF Because configuration can be different (and depends on the HTML structure of component) which are actually tables with columns defintions. That why I prefer keep HTML and initialisation script together.

Comment: @Bardo ... I can't see how it could solve problem - I would need to know where to insert the node. Return to the same point.

Comment: Instead of going wetting your code (not DRY), why not go back to my previous suggestion, and use `data-` attributes on the elements for configuration variables?

Comment: Once you add it to document you can position it through CSS (directly into your component code), you don't need to insert it specifically in one place

Answer (score 3):

Keep your code [DRY (don't repeat yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you have a bunch of `script` elements which can be avoided.

I suggest using `class` to identify elements which need to be initialized, and keep configuration with the elements by means of `data-` attributes.

Eg.

```
<div class="component" data-config1="1" data-config2="2"> ... </div>
...
<!-- At end of HTML page -->
<script>
  $(".component").each(function(idx, elem)
  {
     var componentApi = new MyModule.MyComponent(elem);
     var $elem = $(elem);
     componentApi.config1 = $elem.data("config1");
     // etc...
     //configure component through componentApi 
  }
</script>
```

Or even, if it's more convenient for you

```
var myData = function(key){$elem.data(key);};
```

and then

```
componentApi.config1 = myData("config1");
```

Comment: Thank you JNF. I'm not sure that wish to keep component HTML and component js configuration together harms DRY principle. They both compose "the  configuration". And second, configuring the hierarchichy is not easy with flat `data-` attributes.

Comment: If I have two thousand HTML fragments that would all use the same script file, and two thousand scripts that all use the same HTML file, that's a situation where you would undoubtedly end up repeating yourself. Even if in most scenarios you end up having matched files (*.js, *.html), that amount of separation isn't really harmful. If large amounts of functionality are different, scripts can be extended to a different version, which uses the old one's code.

Comment: @Katana314 not necessary, "popular configuration" (fully or partially reused) can be encapsulated into another "outer" component. Of course only if there will be found the the way to do not rely on fixed `id` . Only fixed `id` value prevents encapsulation there. Of course I understand that `id` can be generated in the moment of creating HTML/DOM, but search the possibility to escape it.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij My company uses the dojo framework, which for each component, allows you to set `data-dojo-attach-point` attributes on elements you'd like to identify. On component startup, it scans the elements for that attribute, and associates it with the relevant object (so you can have 10 components of that type with simple element naming, and no IDs). Even if you don't decide to use dojo, maybe you could put together a similar system.

Comment: @Katana314 - Thank you very much. I  put dojo to my list. Possibly I should already jump to dojo/react/angular but my brains created that way that before going to use any framework I trying to find the solution of the problem by myself. Then it will help a lot to understand what I need from framework.